# Finding distance distribution between a random point and a known point in a circle

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, analytic-geometry

[image]

Here is a circle with radius R. Its is known that any random point in a circle has distribution $f(r)=\dfrac{2r}{R^2}$. I want to know the distance between any chosen point on the circle and a fixed point (x2,y2) on the circle.
Any help?